# Cannot log in into samba share with smbclient but mount it via cifs

Tags: mount, cifs, smb, nas, smbclient

**The problem**

We have a NAS, which I can easily mount via CIFS, but I cannot access it via smbclient. On the NAS itself I have very little influence. I just got a permission for a set of shares there.

**What works**

The mount via fstab works flawlessly via

```
//nasname.local/someshare /mnt/someshare cifs credentials=/home/.cifs/cifscredentials,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```

I can also list the shares via `smbclient` via `smbclient -L //nasname.local/ -N` when i log in anonymously

```
Anonymous login successful

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (NAS Server)
    Backup          Disk      
    Public          Disk      System default share
    Web             Disk      System default share
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
Anonymous login successful

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            xxx
```

**What doesnt work**

I take now the same credentials to log into the NAS via smbclient
`smbclient //nasname.local/someshare -U username` and the the password, but I get the response

```
Enter WORKGROUP\username's password: 
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

So I'd like to know, what the problem could be, that a cifs-mount works but a connection via smbclient doesnt.

**Solution**
c.f. further below

Comment: When you mount it, can you see the contents of that top-level folder? Or doyou have to cd to a subfolder that you have permissions on?

Comment: You mean, to directly mount
`mount //nasname.local/` instead of `mount //nasname.localWeb/`?
If yes, then it doesn't work, to directly mount the top-level folder. 
I have to directly specifiy the service name as 
`do mount -t cifs -o credentials=~/.cifs //nasname.local/Web /mount/dir/`

Comment: Thx to your comment, i looked again into my issue, and was able to solve it. I'll post the solution to my orignal post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was now able to get it work via

- Providing the credentials in a file, looking like

  ```
  username = my_user_name
  password = my_secret_password
  ```
- calling the smbclient via

  ```
  smbclient //nasname.local/Web -A /my/credentials/file
  ```

And it's important, that in the file on uses `username` instead of only `user` (eventhough the latter works if one mounts via `sudo mount -t cifs`)